# Find values of $a, b, c,$ and $d$ that satisfy the condition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**Question:** Every $2$ x $2$ grid contains four non-zero positive digits $(a, b; c, d)$, one in each cell. The sum of the four two digit positive integers created by the two rows and two columns of a grid is denoted **S**$(a, b; c, d)$. For example, **S**$(3, 4; 9, 8)$ = $34 + 98 + 39 + 48 = 219$. What is the total number of possible distinct grids $(a, b; c, 
d)$ such that **S**$(a, b; c, d) = 104$?

**My solution:**

We know that since $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are all non-digits, $ 0 \geq a, b, c, d \leq 9$.

We also know that a two digit number can be written as $10x + y$, where $x$ is the tens digit of the number and $y$ is the ones digit.

So, we want to solve the equation (for non-zero digits $a, b, c,$ and $d$):

$10a + b + 10c + d + 10a + c + 10b + d = 104 \Longrightarrow 20a + 2d + 11b + 11c = 104.$

We can rewrite this equation as $20a + 2d + 11(b + c) = 104$.

Firstly, to solve this equation for digits $a, b, c$, and $d$, we realize that $a \leq 4$. This is because, if $a \geq 6$, then $b, c,$ and $d$ would be negative since $20*6 = 120 > 104$. If $a$ was $5$, then even if $b, c,$ and $d$ were all $1$ (the lowest non-zero digit), the equation's value would be over $104$. Hence, $a \leq 4$.

From here, the equation is a simple case-bash with trying the values for $a$ being $1, 2, 3$, and $4$.

If $a = 4$, then the only possible value for $b, c,$ and $d$ are $1$. So there's only $1$ $(a, b, c, d)$ that works.

If $a = 3$, $2d + 11(b + c) = 44$. There are no cases that work because if $b + c$ is an odd number, then $2d$ would have to be odd, which doesn't happen. So, if $b + c$ is an even number, the only two cases that work are $b + c = 2, 4$. However, in each case, $d = 0, 11$. So, $a = 3$ has no valid cases.

If $a = 2$, $2d + 11(b + c) = 64$. Similarily, like for the case of $a = 3$, there are no cases because it would break the constraint for $d$ being a digit.

If $a = 1$, $2d + 11(b + c) = 84$. We have a value for $b + c$ that works! $b + c = 6$. If $b + c = 6$, then $d = 9$. So, the values for this case for $(b, c, d)$, are $(1, 5, 9), (2, 4, 9), (3, 3, 9), (4, 2, 9),$ and $(5, 1, 9)$, respectively for $b, c,$ and $d$. Hence, there are $5$  $(a, b, c, d)$ that work.

So, the answer = $1 + 0 + 0 + 5 = \boxed{6}$ cases for $(a, b, c, d)$ that work.

Feel free to check over my solution and give me feedback on it (if my solution was too long, faster way, etc ...). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your approach is good. It is the way that I would have taken (the cases are few and obvious, checking the details in each caseis easy). Even in the event that there's a quick approach, it likely would have taken more time to come up with it than to just directly run through the cases)

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks for the review.

Comment: Depending on how comfortable you are with modulo arithmetic, you can make the observation that $ 2 ( d-a) \equiv 104 \pmod{11} \Rightarrow d \equiv a + 8 \pmod{11}$. This explains why $ a = 2, 3 $ have no solutions for $d$ (It's essentially the same argument as what you have, just presented in a quicker manner because of the terminology)

Comment: @CalvinLin yes I realized that after I wrote this solution :)

Comment: If $b+c=6$ and $d=6$ then don't you have $2d+11(b+c)=12+66=78\neq 84$?

Comment: @Alan oops I meant d = 9. Thanks :)

Comment: *nod* took me a moment to realize you just need $84-2d$ to be a multiple of 11, and since you can't hit 77 you need to go down to 66.